# How do I execute methods based on which observable is emitted? But at first, I need to depend on both the observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

```
 combineLatest(data$, order$).subscribe(([data, order]: any) => {
  if (order && data) {
    this.setData(data);
    this.setOrder(order);
  }
});
```

The current scenario is that-we wait for **data$** and **order$** to return observables-data and order, and using **data** and **order**, we perform two methods-
**this.setData(data)** and
**this.setOrder(order)**;

**this.setOrder(order)** depends on  **this.setData(data)** initially.

My expectation is, On ngOnInit the same behaviour initially, but on successive emission of observables(due to change in state(triggered within the ngOnInit))-
something like-

```
if change in data${
    Dont call this.setOrder(order); call this.setData(data);
}and if change in order${
    Dont call this.setData(data); call this.setOrder(order);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: process first next notification by using first() on combineLatest(). Later you can use skip(1) to skip first notifications from both the observervables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go with `combineLatest`, then you loose the information about which observable emitted the value, because `combineLatest` will emit the latest value from all the source observables (given that both emitted at least one value). To overcome this, and still keep your behavior (setData and setOrder when both are available), you could do something like this:

```
const orderData$ = combineLatest(data$, order$).pipe(
  filter(([data, order]) => !!data && !!order),
  first()
);

data$.pipe(skipUntil(orderData$)).subscribe(data => {
  this.setData(data);
});
order$.pipe(skipUntil(orderData$)).subscribe(order => {
  this.setOrder(order);
});

orderData$.subscribe(([data, order]) => {
  this.setData(data);
  this.setOrder(order);
});
```

[The `skipUntil` operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/skipUntil) causes the observable stream to skip the emission of values ​​until the passed in observable emits the first value.

Comment: Hi Octavian, thanks for your answer. It works perfectly on my use case.